# R heatmap newbie: plot pair counts

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I need to create a heatmap showing distinct (charCount, wordCount) pair counts (where `charCount` is a number of chars and `wordCount` is a number of words in text abstracts).
As input I have a csv file where each line has two numbers: `charCount` and `wordCount`. I can read this into matrix and then plot heatmap:

```
data = read.csv("chars_words.txt", sep=",", header=FALSE)
mtx <- as.matrix(data)
heatmap(mtx)
```

Yet for the following data:

```
charCount, wordCount
1000,100
1000,100
1000,100
900,90
800,80
700,70
600,60
500,50
300,30
200,20
100,10​
```

I get a plot of two colors only. How can I create a plot showing distinct (charCount, wordCount) pair counts with color?

*** Update 2:

This code from [moto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4964651/mtoto) solves my problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Convert your data into frequency matrix, then data.frame
df<-data.frame(table(data))

# Set columns ready for ggplot
df$Freq<-as.factor(df$Freq)
df$charCount<-as.character(df$charCount) %>% as.numeric()
df$wordCount<-as.character(df$wordCount) %>% as.numeric()

# plot using ggplot
ggplot(df,aes(x=charCount,y=wordCount)) +
geom_tile(aes(fill=Freq)) +
geom_text(aes(label=Freq))
```

Which results in a nice plot (example data, not from original task):

[image: Pair Distribution]

Comment: Please see corrected question, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

Not exactly sure how you'd do it with the `heatmap()` function, but this `ggplot` approach might work for you:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Convert your data into frequency matrix, then data.frame
df<-data.frame(table(data))

# Set columns ready for ggplot
df$Freq<-as.factor(df$Freq)
df$charCount<-as.character(df$charCount) %>% as.numeric()
df$wordCount<-as.character(df$wordCount) %>% as.numeric()

# plot using ggplot
ggplot(df,aes(x=charCount,y=wordCount)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill=Freq)) +
    geom_text(aes(label=Freq))
```

You can add additional arguments to the ggplot line if you'd like to customize colors etc.

Comment: Thanks! It would be great also to display pair frequencies with color gradient. So,for example, if pair (1000, 99) occurs 10 times in a data set, then corresponding dot is dark red, while pair (300, 13)  that occurs 3 time becomes a light blue dot. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Please, see my question update. Is it possible to adjust ggplot x and y max values to fit small numbers?

Comment: I think the updated answer is what you might be looking for, let me know.